# Why does the implementation contract give me the wrong token symbol when called from ethers?

Tags: etherscan, ethers.js, proxy-contracts

I am trying to get the symbol and decimals for tokens. I have come to realize that some contracts are mere proxies and their implementations are somewhere else. This is where the confusion kicks in.

I have successfully gotten the address of the `implementation` contract, and from it I am able to get the ABI. However, the `implementation` contracts data such as `symbol` or `decimals` is different than that of `proxy` contract.

For example, if you check WBTC token here - https://polygonscan.com/token/0x1bfd67037b42cf73acf2047067bd4f2c47d9bfd6#readContract

In `Read as Proxy` you can see that the symbol is `WBTC`, however if you go to its implementation contract at https://polygonscan.com/address/0x7ffb3d637014488b63fb9858e279385685afc1e2#code, it says `USDT`. This is exactly what I am getting in my code.

How do I get `WBTC` for `WBTC` and not `USDT`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the proxy pattern usually works is that the main token address - `0x1bfd67037b42cf73acf2047067bd4f2c47d9bfd6` in your case - holds the contract's  *storage*, and forwards all function calls to the `implementation` contract using `delegatecall`. This will execute the functions in `implementation` contract on the storage of the main proxy contract.

So if you want to read the right storage values, you need to read them from the main proxy contract.

You can use the implementation contract's ABI on the main proxy contract itself.

Comment: Oh wow, that cleared up a lot of things! It worked, thank you so much for answering.